# Picklist values from different object not retrieving

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, getpicklistvalues, getobjectinfo

I am trying to fetch two picklist values from two different objects but I am only able to get one field from either of the object. Not sure if there is any limitation that only one object field can be retrieved in a single LWC component. Below is the code which I am using if I comment out caseObjectinfo one other is working and If I comment out claimLineItemObjectInfo other is working but both are not working at the same time.

```
import TARGET_STATUS from '@salesforce/schema/Claim_Line_Item__c.Target_Status__c';
import SUBMISSION_HANDOVER_STATUS from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Submission_Handover_Process_Status__c';
import CLAIM_LINE_ITEM from "@salesforce/schema/Claim_Line_Item__c";
import CASE_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Case";
@api objectApiNames = [CLAIM_LINE_ITEM, CASE_OBJECT];
@api claimLineRecordTypeId;
@api caseRecordTypeId;

 @wire(getObjectInfos, { objectApiNames: '$objectApiNames' })
getObjectInfos({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        data.results.forEach(object => {
            if (object.result.apiName == 'Claim_Line_Item__c') {
                this.claimLineRecordTypeId = object.result.defaultRecordTypeId;
            }
            else if (object.result.apiName == 'Case') {
                this.caseRecordTypeId = object.result.defaultRecordTypeId;
            }
        });
        console.log(this.caseRecordTypeId );
        console.log(this.claimLineRecordTypeId );
        console.log('object==>'+JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    else if (error) {
        console.log('==============Error  ' + error);
    }
}

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$claimLineRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TARGET_STATUS })
getPicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('target==>'+JSON.stringify(data));
        this.targetStatuses = data.values.map(plValue => {
            return {
                label: plValue.label,
                value: plValue.value
            };
        });
        console.log(this.targetStatuses);

    } else if (error) {
        console.log('==============Error  ' + error);
    }
}

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$caseRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: SUBMISSION_HANDOVER_STATUS })
getPicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('data==>'+JSON.stringify(data));
        this.submissionHandoverStatuses = data.values.map(plValue => {
            return {
                label: plValue.label,
                value: plValue.value
            };
        });
        console.log(this.submissionHandoverStatuses);

    } else if (error) {
        console.log('==============Error  ' + error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the wire functions of getPicklistValues are given the same name leading to function override. Please provide different names to both wire functions of getPicklistValues.